# rewrite URL in .htaccess for diffrent variables

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to rewrite the URL of my website for PHP page I have different conditions

```
 first example.com/view.php?id=1
```

Here I need to hide id from the URL I need it like this

```
example.com/view/1
```

second, for some page, I have different variable like this example

```
example.com/view/book.php?id=1&user=33333&booked=1
```

I need to rewrite link to this example

```
example.com/view/book/1/33333/1
```

here is what I did in .htaccess page

```
# Remove .php file extension on requests
RewriteRule ^(.+).php$ /$1 [R,L]

RewriteRule ^(view/booked)/([0-9]*)$ $1.php?id=$2 [END]

# Append .php extension for other requests
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ /$1.php [END]

RewriteRule ^(view/book)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)/([0-9]*)$ $1.php?id=$2&user=$3&booked=$4 [END]
```

for example 1 it works well **example.com/view/1** without any problem and for **example.com/view/booked/1** as well.

The only problem with the second example **example.com/view/book.php?id=1&user=33333&booked=1** I need to hide variables

Answer (score 1):

With your shown samples please try following .htaccess rules.

***Please make sure to:***

- Clear your browser cache before testing your URLs.
- Please make sure your .htaccess file is residing along with `view` folder AND `view.php` in same root folder.

```
RewriteEngine ON

##Redirect from example.com/view.php?id=1 To example.com/view/1 rules.
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=301,L]

##Internal handling to rewrite to view.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/?$ $1.php?id=$2 [QSA,L]

##Redirect from example.com/view/book.php?id=1&user=33333&booked=1 TO example.com/view/book/1/33333/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/(view)/([^.]*)\.php\?id=(\d+)&user=(\d+)&booked=(\d+)\s [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3/%4/%5? [R=301,L]

##Internal handling to rewrite to book.php file.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)?$ $1/$2.php?id=$3&user=$4&booked=$5 [QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend to keep things clear and precise. That probably is what you are looking for:

```
RewriteEngine on

# redirect /view/book.php?id=1&user=33333&booked=1 => /view/book/1/33333/1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)&user(\d+)&booked=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?view/book\.php$ /view/book/%1/%2/%3 [R=301,END]

# redirect /view.php?id=1 => /view/1
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=(\d+)$
RewriteRule ^/?view\.php$ /view/%1 [R=301,END]

# rewrite /view/1 => /view.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^/?view/(\d+)$ /view.php?id=$1 [END]

# rewrite /view/book/1/33333/1 => /view/book.php?id=1&user=33333&booked=1
RewriteRule ^/?view/book/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)$ /view/book.php?id=$1&user=$2&booked=$3 [END]

# rewrite to php files, if those exist
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php [END]
```

It probably makes sense to start using `R=302` *temporary* redirections first. And to only change those to `R=301` *permanent* redirections once everything works as desired. That prevents nasty caching issues on the client side. Also you always want to test using a fresh anonymous browser window.

Best place to implement such rules is in the central http server's host configuration. If you do not have access to that you can use a *distributed* configuration file instead (".htaccess"), *if you have enabled the consideration of such files in the http server* ... Above rules will work likewise if that file is placed inside the `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder of the http host.

Comment: Hi @arkascha I got an error when I try to visit example.com/view/book/1/1/1
`Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.`

Comment: I don't spot an immediate issue with the code above. You will have to debug. Is that 404 raised on protocol level or by your script? Does the script `/view/book.php` exist, is it actually called or not? Where did you place that configuration file and how did you enable the http server to interpret such files?